# Data not going to url through Ajax Request

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
                var Order = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
                //dataArr = Order.split('_');

                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                         url: 'updatepriority.php',
                        data: 'sort_order=' + Order,
                        success:function(result){

                        }
                    });
            }
        });
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });
</script>
```

i am using the following code to send data to url , but its not working properly.what i am missing here

```
<form action="updatepriority.php" method="post">
<div id="sortable">
<?php
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  { 
  ?>

  <div id="<?php echo $row['Property_ID']; ?>_<?php echo $row['Priority']; ?>_<?php echo $row['property_type']; ?>"><?php echo $row['property_type']; ?>-<?php echo $row['Desc']; ?>-<?php echo $row['Priority']; ?></div>
 <?php $i++; }
?>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
```

i am trying to sort the data dynamically on drag drop.

Comment: Sure it's not going? (use firebug to check if there are HTTP requests. Also, what do you do on success (empty block there)

Comment: How to: read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing data as following code

```
data: { 'sort_order' : Order}
```

Comment: what should be there for success function & is it mandatory to use success function

Comment: if you don't need to do anything after the success of the ajax  request, then no need to put it

Answer (score 1):

use javascript  associative array

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
                var Order = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
                //dataArr = Order.split('_');

                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                         url: 'updatepriority.php',
                        data: {sort_order:Order},
                        success:function(result){

                        }
                    });
            }
        });
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });
</script>
```